# Try Catch to Handle Exception

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to update some documents in DocumentDb / CosmosDb, and if that fails, need to do something else, and then if that fails to log it out...

```
try { 
    do a thing w/ database
}
catch (DocumentClientException dce1) {
    try {
        do another, alternative thing w/ database
    }
    catch (DocumentClientException dce2) {
        log to app insights.
    }
}
```

I'm not sure about this, it seems clunky.. what do you guys think?

For additional bonus points, I need to do this quite frequently.. so something that I can farm off somewhere would be even better ;)

Comment: I don't see nor bad nor good things in your approach. Generally, you should avoid situations where exception generated in your catch/finally/dispose block. Because if it is - it's pretty much identify fatal error and state of your system is overall corrupted or undefined (which is a lot worse than corrupted - you don't even know whats happening anymore).

Comment: Indeed, this is especially about optimistic concurrency w/ CosmosDb in which you essentially need to execute commands against the db, and kinda of expect it to fail... in this scenario my alternative is a compensating backout, which ofc.. might also fail

Comment: Then you should separate try/retry/fail logic in three different functions. They don't need to know about what exception occured (it is decided inside function) - they just do things. Nothing more. I would prefer general extension which performs retry upon fail as many times as you want with any sleepoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd avoid intermixing exception flow with a functional logic flow. It can get brittle. Instead, convert the exception into a logical flag and use it in ordinary logic constructs.

So step 1 is catch the exception and set a variable or return value based on it, and wrap this in an independent method to mask the messiness from everyone else:

```
bool TryDoSomethingWithDataBase()
{
    try
    {
        //Do thing that could fail
        return true;
    }
    catch(SpecificException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool TryDoSomethingElseWithDataBase()
{
    try
    {
        //Do thing that could fail
        return true;
    }
    catch(SpecificException ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Step 2 is to write the logic as usual:

```
if (!TryDoSomethingWithDatabase())
{
    if (!TryDoSomethingElseWithDatabase())
    {
        LogFatalError();
    }
}
```

Or

```
var ok = TryDoSomethingWithDatabase();
if (ok) return;
ok = TryDoSomethingElseWithDatabase();
if (ok) return;
LogFatalError();
```

Comment: i went with this approach as when polling some of the guys i work with, they also mostly (unprompted) went for this too.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would your thing with the Database fail? You would be better coding for the conditionals you are aware of and expecting and do different things if you want to go into a different logic for processing the result.

Try catch will catch anything and everything, so if your connection to the db fails etc or if you are trying to read or insert malformed data etc.

Try catch does have various exceptions that you can investigate further and catch the specific exception you are interested in.. e.g.

```
try
   //try something
catch (Exception ex)            
{                
    if (ex is FormatException || ex is OverflowException)
    {
        //Do something specific;
        return;
    }

    throw;
}
```

Comment: my actual code will catch a collision on the cosmosdb etag, when another thread has already edited the document...

Comment: I think if you are after catching concurrency issues and collisions on the cosmosdb then yes your try catch is the best approach i think here. I would implement what @IdoRan is suggesting and break each one down into two separate functions / methods and call one in the catch section when the first try has failed.

Answer (score 0):

This is ok but if you say you'll have this over and over it's better to extract that logic and reuse it.
One way of doing this is to have a method that accept the first and section actions as parameters, for example:

```
public void TryThis(Action doFirst, Action doSecond)
{
  try { 
      doFirst();
  }
  catch (DocumentClientException dce1) {
      try {
          doSecond();
      }
      catch (DocumentClientException dce2) {
          log to app insights.
      }
  }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
public void DoSomethig1()
{
...
}

public void DoSomething2()
{
...
}

TryThis(DoSomething1, DoSomething2)
```